# difference b/w angular 2 Webpack and Angular 2 Webpack starter?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webpack

Actually I want to start a project and I already done angular2-webpack with given example.

[angular2-Webpack](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html)

And today I somewhere read about Webpack starter. I want to know the difference b/w in both. And what should I go with and why?.
 suggest please.
 thanks in advance.